# Google Form Responses in a Notification Email

Tags: forms, email, google-sheets

I'm using the Form Notifications add-on in a Google Form. I've edited the Code.gs and CreatorNotification.html files and all works fine - when a Google Form is submitted I get an email. Now I'm trying to get some of the fields from that Form submission into the email. But with the edits I've added below, the email notification stops working.

In the Code.gs script I have:

```
function sendCreatorNotification() {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var settings = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    var responseStep = settings.getProperty('responseStep');
    responseStep = responseStep ? parseInt(responseStep) : 10;

    function onFormSubmit(e) {
        //Get information from form and set as variables
        var First_Name = e.value[2];

        // If the total number of form responses is an even multiple of the
        // response step setting, send a notification email(s) to the form
        // creator(s). For example, if the response step is 10, notifications
        // will be sent when there are 10, 20, 30, etc. total form responses
        // received.
        if (form.getResponses().length % responseStep == 0) {
            var addresses = settings.getProperty('creatorEmail').split(',');
            if (MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota() > addresses.length) {
                var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('CreatorNotification');
                template.summary = form.getSummaryUrl();
                template.responses = form.getResponses().length;
                template.title = form.getTitle();
                template.responseStep = responseStep;
                template.formUrl = form.getEditUrl();
                template.notice = NOTICE;
                template.firstname = First_Name;
                var message = template.evaluate();
                MailApp.sendEmail(settings.getProperty('creatorEmail'),
                form.getTitle() + ': Case submission',
                message.getContent(), {
                    name: ADDON_TITLE,
                    htmlBody: message.getContent()
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the CreatorNotification.html I have:

```
<p><i>Form Notifications</i> (a Google Forms add-on) has detected that the      form
titled <a href="<?= formUrl?>"><b><?= title ?></b></a> has received
<?= responses ?> responses so far.</p>

<p><a href="<?= summary ?>">Summary of form responses</a></p>

<p>First Name:</p> <?= firstname ?>
```

Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to debug the code and find out what line is failing if you don't know now.  Add `Logger.log('this value: ' + variableName);` statements where you want to check the value of a variable, then VIEW the LOGS, or step through the code with the debugger.  [Debugger and breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)

Comment: You now have the `onFormSubmit` function inside of the `sendCreatorNotification()` function.  Is that the way it originally was?

Comment: I have added the onFormSubmit function expecting it to work. It was not there originally. If I remove it, the email notification will work again. So, I guess the question is, how do I populate the variable (one or more of the responses in the form) into the template?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run *two* triggers.  That "Add-on" code creates a trigger.  The Add-on creates an "Installable" trigger.  You already have one trigger set up for the form being submitted.  The `onFormSubmit(e)` function is a "Simple" trigger.  So, you have two triggers set up to run when a form is submitted.  So, you created a conflict.  If you look in the RESOURCES menu, under CURRENT PROJECT's TRIGGERS, you should see a trigger defined for the `sendCreatorNotification()` function.

Here's what you can try.    You don't need a seperate `onFormSubmit(e)` simple trigger. The `sendCreatorNotification()` function, has the event object available to it.  Just add `e` to the `sendCreatorNotification()` function:

```
sendCreatorNotification(e)
```

The write your code to get the value out of `e`.

Comment: No, all I added were these lines: 


    function onFormSubmit(e) {
        //Get information from form and set as variables
        var First_Name = e.value[2];

      template.firstname = First_Name;


    }


The original code can be found here:

https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-form-notifications-addon

Comment: OK, I am now using sendCreatorNotification(e) and removed the superfluous trigger. However, it doesn't seem to like the code to get the value from the Google Sheet. Debug mode shows this error: Cannot read property "values" from undefined for the line: var First_Name  = e.values[1];